# Specifying multiple classes with type hinting

Tags: python, class, oop, annotations, type-hinting

How can I specify multiple classes using type hinting?

To be more clear, I'll give an example. I have this function called weigh and it gets an object as a parameter and returns its weight (private attribute). However, I want to weigh only potatoes and onions, but not tomatoes, and by using annotations I should get a warning if I tried to weigh a tomato.

Here's some code for that:

```
class Potato:

    def __init__(self, weight: float):
        self.__weight = weight

    @property
    def weight(self) -> float:
        return self.__weight


class Onion:

    def __init__(self, weight: float):
        self.__weight = weight

    @property
    def weight(self) -> float:
        return self.__weight


class Tomato:

    def __init__(self, weight: float):
        self.__weight = weight

    @property
    def weight(self) -> float:
        return self.__weight


def weigh(object_: annotation) -> float: 
# here there should be an annotation for classes Potato and Onion
    return object_.weight


p = Potato(402.9)
o = Onion(199)
t = Tomato(155.6)  

print(weigh(p))
print(weigh(o))
print(weigh(t))  # this shouldn't be possible
```

Comment: You can use `Union[Potato, Onion]`

Comment: What you’re doing seems deliberately opposed to OOP. You can weigh anything with a weight, you could even have a Weighable abstract base class.

Comment: I'd agree with @jonrsharpe, create a `Weighable` base class which has the `weigh` function. Python doesn't really have such a thing as private attributes or type requirements. Only conventions

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from typing import Union    
def weigh(object_: Union[Potato, Onion]) -> float:
    return object_.weight
t = Tomato(155.6)
print(weigh(t))
```

Which gets flagged as

```
Argument 1 to "weigh" has incompatible type "Tomato"; expected "Union[Potato, Onion]"
```